# Can't output multidimensional matrix in Matlab function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, simulink

For example I have function that creates matrix 2x2 : [1 2; 3 4]
I have such simple function:

```
function[result] = Rho(x)
// I've tried and so:
result = [1 2; 3 4];
// And so:
result(1,1) = 1;
result(1,2) = 2;
result(2,1) = 3;
result(2,2) = 4;
```

In Matlab window i see right result:

```
>> Rho(1)
ans =
     1     2
     3     4
```

But in Simulink I always get [1;2;3;4]. Where is my mistake?

[image]

P.S. I forgot to remove argument x of function, because in real function I make matrix depending on argument x. But it doesn't play role in our example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is likely due to the parameter settings for your **MATLAB Function block** (now called an [**Interpreted MATLAB Function block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html) in newer versions). Take a look at the Parameters Dialog Box for that block:

[image]

Note that you will want to set the **Output dimensions** to 2 and uncheck the **Collapse 2-D results to 1-D** check box. If this is left checked, then your 2-by-2 matrix will be turned into a 1-D array by extracting values along each column from left to right, which ends up being `[1 3 2 4]` in your example.

Once you apply the above changes, then all you should have to do is resize your [**Display block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/display.html) so that it shows your 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. I've should notice this option in block properties))